# Hibernate enforcing relation with "central" entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Supposing I have the following entities relations:

- One Person has Many Pets
- One Person has Many Toys
- One Pet has Many Toys

> Person 1     ----> * Pet
>
> Person 1     ----> * Toy
>
> Pet    *  ----> * Toy

I would like to enforce the fact that **One Pet can only have Toys from the Person owning him.** I don't know if it's possible to do that at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating custom check constraint, below link will help you to do so:-

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-customconstraints

And inside the **isValid()** method of **ConstraintValidator** you can get the list of toyIds of person and validate them against your Input List of toyId's

```
public class ValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckCase, String> {

private ValueMode valueMode;

public void initialize(CheckCase constraintAnnotation) {
    this.valueMode= constraintAnnotation.value();
}

public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

  // You can have your logic here and can validate the same.
   // Here you can fetch the ToyIds and validate the same from below list of ToyIds
//select p.toyID from Person p join Toy t where p.toyID = t.toyId and p.petId in (Input list of toyids)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know if it's possible to create such a constraint at the database level.